# is there a way to have the if statements' condition to have the previous condition plus something?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a question about the if elif statement. When I write an if elif statement and I want them to execute one at the time, in order and a specific amount of times, is there a better way to do it than have a time variable and have all the conditions be a long line afterward?

example in python:

```
time = 0   
wait1 = 1   
wait2 = 4   
wait3 = 2

while True:
    if time < wait1:
        print("1")
    elif time < wait1 + wait2:
        print("2") 
    elif time < wait1 + wait2 + wait3:
        print("3")
    time += 1
```

is there a way to have the if statements' condition to have the previous condition plus something, instead of writing the long line of condition afterward?

maby something like:

```
time = 0    
wait1 = 1    
wait2 = 4    
wait3 = 2    

while True:
    if time < wait1:
        print("1")
    elif time < (previous condition) + wait2:
        print("2") 
    elif time < (previous condition) + wait3:
        print("3")
    time += 1
```

Comment: Simply put: no - no way. Why not simply declare `wait2 = wait1 + 4` and `wait3 = wait2 + 2` to begin with? then your _conditions_ get shorter - not that this would any difference computingwise.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm not sure I fully understand the question but hopefully this helps.

```
import time
value = 2
otherValue = 4
while True:
    if value < otherValue:
        value = value * 2
        otherValue = otherValue * 2
        print("The value variable and condition is now: " + str(value))
        print("The otherValue variable and condition is now: " + str(otherValue))
        time.sleep(1)
```